# How to query for a row with a specific DateTime value using GQL?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, gql

I tried just using the date's string representation but it didn't work (i.e. no results):

```
gql = "SELECT * from Shout where when='2010-11-05 16:57:45.675612'"
```

This is my Shout class:

```
class Shout(db.Model):
   message= db.StringProperty(required=True)
   when = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
   who = db.StringProperty()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gql = "SELECT * FROM Shout WHERE when = DATETIME('2010-11-05 16:57:45')"
```

Per [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html), use the following for date/time literals:

- `DATETIME()` with timestamps,
- `DATE()` with dates,
- `TIME()` with times

An alternative syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM Shout WHERE when = DATETIME(2010,11,5,16,57,45)
```